# How to create a user in postgres and to give grantall privileges

Tags: postgresql, rds

I'm new to PostgreSQL and I have created a postgres instance in the AWS RDS and I have also created a new user. Now I would like to grant all privileges to that user for creating new databases and to perform all admin operations.

I have found the below query to do that but it was providing access only to a particular database and that user is unable to create a new database.

```
GRANT ALL ON DATABASE workflow TO cnwrkstag;
```

I have also tried to provide access as a super user of RDS but I'm getting an error as I am unable to so because it should be a super user.

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 0):

You must be very careful with the super users, you can doit this way:

```
ALTER ROLE role_name SUPERUSER;
```

Or

```
ALTER USER user_name SUPERUSER;
```

Here is the documentation:

[Alter-role](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/sql-alterrole.html)

Comment: I'm getting the below error: logged in with user which we creates during instance creation.
testpg=> ALTER USER saravana SUPERUSER;
ERROR:  must be superuser to alter superusers

Comment: You must to login with one of the users of the result of this query: SELECT rolname FROM pg_role WHERE rolsuper; and the error is indicating tha saravana user is already a super user

Comment: When i logged in with the user 'saravana'. i couldnt able to create a database. 
testpg=> SELECT rolname FROM pg_role WHERE rolsuper;
ERROR:  relation "pg_role" does not exist